# How to Properly Use wx.CallLater in wx.Python

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, wxpython

I want to loop and call a function every 1000 milliseconds with wx.CallLater. I implemented this (see below), but it does not factor in the delay - it seems to execute automatically. How can I get this to wait 1000 milliseconds between function calls?

This function is within a class. In my main module, I instantiate an object of this class and call the task_loop function. I intend to keep the loop going until will_break is set to True, and task_loop returns the work_session_agenda in the main module. Thank you for your help!

```
def task_loop(self, duration, window, task, work_session_agenda, start, completed):

    will_break = False
    will_continue = False

    duration -= datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

## More code in here - which, depending on conditionals, sets the values of will_break and will_continue

```
    if will_break:
        print('BREAKING')
        return work_session_agenda
    else:
        print('GOT HERE')
        timer = wx.CallLater(1000, self.task_loop, duration, window, task, work_session_agenda, start, completed)
```

Comment: Use a wx.Timer which supports sending an event at a fixed interval.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would I go about implementing that? I’ve tried using wx.Timer in the past but to no avail.

Comment: what do you mean "it does not factor in the delay"? If that's how you're using `CallLater` it will be correctly delayed by 1 second.

Comment: @user2682863 It does not delay by 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find an example with `wx.CallLater` and with `wx.Timer` as suggested in the comments. Notice that in both cases the GUI remains responsive during the waiting time.

With `wx.Timer`

```
import wx
import time

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="With wx.Timer", size=(500,500))

        #### Variables
        self.will_continue = True
        self.i = 0
        self.total = 5
        self.mili = 1000

        #### Widgets
        # Parent panel
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        # Button
        self.button  = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Start", pos=(50, 50))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button", pos=(50 ,100))

        #### Timer Notice that wx.Timer is own by the frame itself
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

        #### Bind
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnCheck, self.timer)

    def OnStart(self, event):
        ## OnStart, disable the button and change its label and start the timer.
        ## Notice with Button that the GUI remain responsive
        ## while the timer runs
        if self.will_continue:
            print(self.i)
            print(time.ctime())
            self.button.SetLabel("Running")
            self.button.Disable()
            self.timer.Start(self.mili)
        ## When finish waiting reset everything so the start button can run 
        ## again and stop the timer
        else:
            self.timer.Stop()
            self.button.SetLabel("Start")
            self.button.Enable()
            self.will_continue = True
            self.i = 0            

    def OnCheck(self, event):
        self.i += 1 
        if self.i > self.total:
            self.will_continue = False
        else:
            pass
        self.OnStart(event)


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

With `wx.CallLater`

```
import wx
import time

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="With wx.CallAfter", size=(500,500))

        #### Variables
        self.will_continue = True
        self.i = 0
        self.total = 5
        self.mili = 1000

        #### Widgets
        # Parent panel
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        # Button
        self.button  = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Start", pos=(50, 50))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button", pos=(50 ,100))

        #### Bind
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)

    def OnStart(self, event):
        ## OnStart, disable the button and change its label and make the 
        ## wx.CallLater call. Notice with Button that the GUI remain responsive
        ## while wx.CallLater waits
        if self.will_continue:
            print(self.i)
            print(time.ctime())
            self.button.SetLabel("Running")
            self.button.Disable()
            wx.CallLater(self.mili, self.OnCheck, event)
        ## When finish waiting reset everything so the start button can run 
        ## again
        else:
            self.button.SetLabel("Start")
            self.button.Enable()
            self.will_continue = True
            self.i = 0            

    def OnCheck(self, event):
        self.i += 1 
        if self.i > self.total:
            self.will_continue = False
        else:
            pass
        self.OnStart(event)


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```